# Combine Physics Bodies in Godot 3D

Tags: game-physics, godot

I want to make a game where you can build your own ship. I want there to be building, something similar to the one in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5fGko-2Xhw&t=6s
Where the physics bodies connect and some of the physics bodies can apply force to the whole thing.
I can't come up with a method to do this in Godot. Does anyone have one they could share?

Comment: Hello ! Unfortunately, this question is out of scope for this website. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. We'll need you to provide us with some concrete code to show what you have tried so far and what is not working. Fortunately for you, ChatGPT is getting very good these days, you might start there !

Comment: Oh okay thanks you. I did not even know an AI could be advanced enough that I could even considered asking it. This world really as advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't combine physic bodies. A single physics body can have multiple colliders (`CollisionShape`) and models (`MeshInstance`). All you have to do is add them as children.

As per the logic to build them in runtime, you can either use `input_ray_pickable` or use a raycast to find where the user is clicking. So you know which position to give to the objects you are attaching.

---

By the way, the video you linked shows a game made in Godot, and there is a link to the source code of the project, which is under MIT license, here: [pawngames/GodotModularBuilder](https://github.com/pawngames/GodotModularBuilder).

Since we have the source code, we might take it as base for a solution.

A quick look confirms that the modules that are attached to the physics body are `CollisionShape` (children of the physics body), and they have `MeshInstance` (children of the `CollisionShape`). To detect where to position them, they use `Area`s with `input_ray_pickable` (also children of the `CollisionShape`, at first glance it is one for each place where you could attach something).

A surprise for me is that they are using `VehicleBody` as the vehicle body.

About applying forces, the design was to have modules communicate with the physics body via signals that tell it what to do.